# Reading multiple generic files with tf.data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to implement an input pipeline with tf.data.
The features are in a matrix exported from matlab while the labels are in other files that require particular functions in order to be read.

The file names that must be loaded can be computed given a number.

This is how I implemented it

```py
def load_files(k):
    mesh_file = file_path(k, "off", flags.dataset_mesh)
    mat_file = file_path(k, "mat", flags.dataset_mat)

    mesh = pymesh.load_mesh(mesh_file)
    mat = scipy.io.loadmat(mat_file)

    return mesh.vertices, mat


def generator_fn():
    return (load_files(x) for x in range(1000000 + 1))


def input_fn() -> Dataset:
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator_fn,
           output_types=(tf.as_dtype(tf.float32), tf.as_dtype(tf.float32)), )
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=flags.batch_size).repeat()
    dataset = dataset.cache()
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=flags.prefetch_buffer_size)
    return dataset
```

The problem is that the GPU usage is very low, around 5% (2080 ti). I'm not sure where the bottleneck is.
I'm testing with a simple MLP, but the gpu usage doesn't seem to change despite the layers or neurons per layer that I add.

I'm performing the training in this way:

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(n_input,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    .
    .
    .
    keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(n_output, activation=None)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(input_fn().make_one_shot_iterator(), steps_per_epoch=1000000, epochs=1)
```

So, I think that the problem may lie: on how I feed the data (the problem *shouldn't* be just the file reading since I'm on a SSD NVMe), on how I do the training, or that it's just a simple network despite the layers that I add.

However, I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to feed the data.

I'm using `tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0a0`, I ran a benchmark from lambda-labs and it was able to use the gpu at 100%

Comment: Try to feed your data using some standard single file format such as TFRecord or HDF5 that will definitely help.

Comment: What datatype does `load_files` return? Have you tried profiling it? 
In what file format are data stored in both `file_path` ? You don't need this `input_fn().make_one_shot_iterator()` I guess the problem is in this line `load_files(x) for x in range`

Comment: I'm a bit busy this week, I'll definetly try to convert the whole dataset (it's quite heavy, around 30GB) in TFRecord. I don't particularly like this idea since I'd like to keep the data compatible with matlab, and I'd like to streamline the dataset production as much as possible.
`load_files` returns two matrices of floats: one with shape (n, 3), i.e. the vertices of a mesh, the other with shape (n,), i.e. a function defined on the vertices of such mesh. I don't know to profile it, I'll have to check it. Why should the problem be the generator?

Comment: Doesn't the GPU load change when you up the `batch_size`?